# Mysql Count multiple columns based on the same values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following like table

```
    A               B
    Yes             OOS
    No              No
    OOS             Yes
    OOS             No
    Yes             No
```

I want to do the following

```
Criteria        A               B
Yes             2               1
No              1               3
OOS             2               1
```

I can get this right with one column like

```
Criteria        A 
Yes             2 
No              1 
OOS             2
```

Here is what I have to achieve the above:

```
SELECT A, count(A) FROM temp_db GROUP BY A;
```

Comment: This might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the values into a single column, so you can use `group by`.  Here is one method:

```
select criteria, sum(A) as A, sum(B) as B
from ((select A as criteria, 1 as A, 0 as B
       from liketable
      ) union all
      (select B, 0, 1
       from liketable
      )
     ) t
group by criteria;
```

Using the `union all` approach is the safest way in MySQL, in case not all `criteria` are in both columns.  The following is a slight tweak that might be a bit better performance-wise:

```
select criteria, sum(A) as A, sum(B) as B
from ((select A as criteria, count(*) as A, 0 as B
       from liketable
       group by A
      ) union all
      (select B, 0, count(*)
       from liketable
       group by B
      )
     ) t
group by criteria;
```

Often doing two aggregations on half the data is more efficient than a bigger aggregation on all the data.

Answer (score 1):

For this sample data, you could do this with a join of derived tables:

```
SELECT qa.Criteria, qa.A, qb.B FROM
(SELECT A AS Criteria, count(A) AS A FROM temp_db GROUP BY A) qa
FULL OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT B AS Criteria, count(B) AS B FROM temp_db GROUP BY B) qb
  ON qa.Criteria=qb.Criteria
```

But if there are missing criteria in the A column, they will not appear in the results of this query, and you would need the UNION ALL approach others have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```
select val, sum(cntA), sum(cntB)
from (SELECT A as val, count(A) as cntA,        0 as cntB FROM temp_db GROUP BY A;
      union all
      SELECT B as val,        0 as cntA, count(B) as cntB FROM temp_db GROUP BY B)
group by val;
```

Comment: Your answer has appeared in the low quality posts queue. Please attach an explanation as to why / how this fixes OPs problem.

Comment: This query is a correct solution for the OPs problem. So please explain why this post is put in the low quality queue.

Comment: As previously stated, you haven't explained how this works or why it addresses the OPs needs.